# Auditd, Syslog and Journald

Tags: kernel, syslog, systemd-journald, audit, linux-audit

I have been investigating about these three logging solutions `auditd`, `syslog`, and `journald`, but still there are thing that unclear to me.

According to the things I read, `auditd` audits events in the kernel and it has very deep and strong view on the system. On the other hand, `syslog` collects logs from several sources on the system (services), and manages them and organizing them.

My questions:

1. What is the difference between `journald` and `auditd`?
2. Should I maintain them all together on my server?
3. which of these components work together and how?

Comment: Autitd produces logs, syslog and journald collect them. journald has the ability to forward to syslog.

Comment: @jordanm, your comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 4):

1- As @jordanm stated : "Autitd produces logs, syslog and journald collect them."

2- You should configure them, if you have special needs for logging.

3- Journald is systemd's logging, but it can aggregate logging from other source,syslog /rsyslog/syslog-ng can scrap journald's logs to parse them and apply a local treatment for them and/or forward them to a remote syslog server.

Sure this is not complete answer, because you should look to what each tool is.